# How can I combine WAR packaging and OSGi bundle creation in Maven?

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-2, osgi

I want to deploy one of my OSGi bundles with a war package structure so it is recognized as a web application by Struts. I use Maven, so I get WAR packaging built-in and I have the Maven bundle-plugin to create the OSGi compatible manifest for me.

The problem is, the two don't work together, so the bundle plugin is not aware that the class files are now in the subfolder `classes/` and the bundled jars are in `lib/`, so it creates a wrong `Bundle-classpath` header. I could manually add the correct header to my `pom.xml`, but I'd like to have that don eautomatically. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Web Project with Apache Felix Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272627/maven-web-project-with-apache-felix-plugin)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to (more or less) achieve this is described on OPS4J Wiki page -- ["Getting the benefits of maven-bundle-plugin in other project types"](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/ops4j/Getting+the+benefits+of+maven-bundle-plugin+in+other+project+types).

You can configure dependency embedding and `Bundle-ClassPath` directive in your `pom.xml` to match the locations used by WAR plugin. The maven-bundle-plugin will then generate correct manifest headers.

The instructions for maven-bundle-plugin might look like this:

```
<instructions>
    <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>

    <Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
    <!-- ... -->
</instructions>
```

---

**ETA**: When using this approach, I found out two noteworthy things:

- the bundle plugin will complain about missing `WEB-INF` directories, because when the manifest goal is executed, the war plugin has not yet created them (it only runs at a later phase)
- although it doesn't make sense for the actual webapp, the `Bundle-ClassPath` directive *must* contain ".", or the bundle plugin will mess up the `Import-Packages` header. I found this in some JIRA issue via Google, but I can't find the URL anymore.

Other than that it works fine.

Comment: +1 for `{maven-dependencies}` (see http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#ApacheFelixMavenBundlePlugin%28BND%29-Embeddingdependencies)

Comment: Great. I sort of knew this but I hadn't seen the `Embed-Directory` directive before.